# MySQL - Changing FT_MIN_WORD_LEN

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, administration, server-administration

I've recently asked my server administrator, for my Windows dedicated server, to change the MySQL configuration file (my.cnf) to allow search words of 2 characters or more, from the default of 4.

They said the changed it, restarted MySQL and re-booted the server but I have seen no changes. I've rebuilt the indexes only on the tables that this particular script uses, using the REPAIR TABLE method but still doesn't work as it should.

Do I have to rebuild all indexes, on all tables, even though they're not being used for this full-text query?

**EDIT**

Is this right? After searching my server for my.ini files? 5.0 is my latest version.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those changes should have been sufficient. You should verify by running this:

```
show variables like 'ft_min_word_len';
```

Typically if you are changing ft_min_word_len you also want to change [ft_stopword_file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file) since many short words are also stopwords. You can just set that variable to '' if you don't want any stopwords. Otherwise specify a path to an alternate stopwords file. That could be your problem, depending on what you are searching for.

Comment: The short words I am searching for are names, such as Al Pacino, Al Murray, Tom Cruise, Ian Wright... it obviously fails to find their first names. I just ran your query and **ft_min-word-len** returns 4 still. So I take it the changes the server administrators did, did not take effect.

Comment: In that case, confirm that the change was made in the "[mysqld]" section of the my.cnf file. If it's in the wrong section it won't work.

Comment: I made a mistake the file is my.ini (windows) and the variable is in [mysql] section of the file. I have just run a search on my server for my.ini files and there are 3 and a weird pattern as to where they are located. I have attached a screenshot to my question as an edit, is that right?

Comment: The files should be C:\windows\my.ini or C:\my.ini, and the variable needs to be set in the [mysqld] section, not the [mysql] section.

Comment: Hi @Ike Consider incorporating that extra information from comments into your answer.